# CSS not applying from style sheet?

Tags: css

I'm not sure why this isn't working but I'm trying to make a transition bar on a page that is basically just a block of color across some content.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 but not sure that has anything to do with it. If I apply the color directly to my div tag using a style tag it will work. However, I would like it to be in my style sheet so I can add a left and right border. When I put the same thing in my style sheet and try to apply it the style it won't display. I'm still learning to use the Dev Tools but when I view it using F12 I looks as though it applies my stylesheet style like it should.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

This works. I'm using a period to control the height for now but will eventually try to apply some height styling.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#6f88a1">.</div>
</div>
```

This doesn't

```
.home_transition_bar
{
    border-left: 1px solid Black;
    border-right: 1px solid Black;
    background-color: #6f88a1;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 home_transition_bar">.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you inspected it to see if there is anything that has more importance than your CSS rule? Try adding `!important` to your background color and see if that works - so `background-color: #6f88a1!important;`

Comment: Works fine for me http://www.bootply.com/R8h7HwT8aV

Comment: Honestly don't know what I did different other than maybe but when I went back to apply the stylesheet style this time it worked? I tried three other times making changes and it the section would act like nothing got applied. Well, at least it's working now. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: @CalvT....thanks for the tip. I should have thought to put the !important but looks like I don't need it now but will try to keep it in mind for next time. Question though, when you said to look and see if that there was anything with more importance, how would I tell that? If there was something with more importance wouldn't it show my style crossed out? When I inspected it I didn't see it crossed out.

Answer (score 0):

well, bootstrap has some pre-defined styles... in order to overwrite them, simple css code might not be accepted. Therefore, try at the end of the style "!important". For example:

```
#header
{
   background-color: red !important;
}
```

I am working with bootstrap and that has done it for me. Hope it helps